# DotNet Nuke Api Not Found - Edit Mode Not Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i have installed dotnetnuke version 7 and then install dnnarticle v9.02 , module have been installed with no error , and all sub module of that works with no problem , but i have problem with `api` addresses that in browser console get 404 error , how i can fix this error while using this module ?

`/DesktopModules/DigitalAssets/API/ContentService` for file manger ,and for control bar  Not found and for control panel in ribbon bar works but in control bar get `/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/controlbar` error , `Edit Mode`  not worked too

Comment: How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior could be due to your application pool is not running .NET framework 4.0 which is required for the WebAPI to work.

Answer (score 0):

**1-** in your `web.config` add set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to `true` if it is false , or add if not exist

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

**2-** Check `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` file exist in your dotnetnuke bin folder , copy fresh and original version from installation file.

It will fix Problem ;)